# How to set a min number of words for a blog post

Tags: php, posts

Just want to say I am beginner I can't write code to well, but I can read it. I run a website were people can post things. When users go to submit a post they can choose to write it on the websites text editor or they can upload a pdf or a docx file. I want to enforce a 500 word **MINIMUM** on all articles. Now the problem.

1. first I need to be able to require that all authors write a minimum of 500 words, before a post can be accepted.
2. The second problem is that I need to enforce the word minimum for uploaded files too.

Comment: Can you define accepted? Uploaded files would be a separate question that has a separate solution, we have a one question per question policy